# Import a mongo database form local to Ubuntu droplet on Digital Ocean?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, digital-ocean

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 droplet on digital ocean. How can I import a database from my the filesystem on my local machine?

My app is built with Meteor. The following when ran from my app's folder locally works:

```
mongorestore --port=3001 ../dump
```

Ive tried SSHing into the server

```
ssh root@<my servers IP>
```

And then running the same command:

```
mongorestore --port=3001 /Users/<my username>/Projects/<project name>/dump
```

But I get an error:

```
The program 'mongorestore' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install mongodb-clients
```

So I tried entering mongod:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo nomad
```

And I get a sucsess message:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nomad
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
```

And I try the same command:

```
mongorestore --port=3001 /Users/<my username>/Projects/<project name>/dump
```

And I get this error:

```
2018-01-13T12:30:25.134+0000 E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15
```

Comment: can you provide a guide on how you were able to accomplish a local mongodump to a digital ocean mongorestore? I'm in the same situation now, also running meteor. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongorestore` is a shell command, you run it from bash. The mongoshell you ran has a limited syntax, so it won't work like that.

You can try something like this:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongorestore  /Users/<my username>/Projects/<project name>/dump
```

The problem is that the project dump you are trying to load is not available to the docker instance, as its file system is isolated from the host server. You could copy the files into the docker instance using `docker cp`, and then load them, but it starts getting messy to do, and docker containers are not really designed to be used this way. The docker container usually only has minimal tools available, and you end up needing to install additional software in order to do these kinds of operations. It then becomes a non standard container, and can't be replaced.

It might be time for you to move to a separate database server, which can be done by using a service such as mlab, or you can create your own droplet to host a mongodb server. Using a service gives you tools that you can easily take backup copies, copy one database to another, restore backups etc using a web control panel. Much easier to do.

Comment: I did considered going with mlab or similar as I'm sure it would be easier. I don't mind the extra cost but wouldn't it be slower to use a database as a service? Sorry I know this is a bit of a separate question, but as requests will be going from the server to the database (which could be very different geographical locations) doesn't this impact page loading speeds?

Comment: If you can get the database server in a similar location it works ok. local on the same machine gives good performance, but might not scale well as both db and meteor are on the same server. mlab doesn't have all locations, so maybe compose.io or mongodb atlas might be better

Comment: Using sftp and unzip ive loaded the database files to my server. When I ssh in and ls I can see that they are there. However the command 'docker exec -it mongodb mongorestore <path-to-files>' I get an error: 'Failed: mongorestore target '<path-to-files>' invalid: stat dbunzip: no such file or directory'. Ive tried a lot of variations around the file path (including root, ./ etc) but I always get the same error.

Comment: You need to put the files in a location where the mongod process can read them. Which basically means on the file system inside the docker container.